# View Top N-Results in Oracle

Tags: oracle10g

I'm trying to do a simple query to show best selling products in the company, specifically the top 3 ones.
To get all results I'm running this query

```
select product_name, (qty_on_order - qty_on_hand) as Sales 
from products, product_inventory
where product_inventory.product_id = products.product_id
order by Sales Desc
```

This returns everything but ordered, but I need to view only the top 3 items, I used ROW_NUMBER but it didn't give me the results that I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
select *
from (select product_name, (qty_on_order - qty_on_hand) as Sales 
      from products join
           product_inventory
           on product_inventory.product_id = products.product_id
      order by Sales Desc
     ) p
where rownum <= 3;
```

Comment: Yes, that's it.
Can you please explain me why do I have to use that method?

Comment: You need a subquery because `where` is processed before `order by`.  So, if you do them in the same query, the first three records encountered will be sorted, rather than all the data being sorted and getting the first three.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this problem by using rank function also, which will be much easier.
Try the following query

select rnk,product_name, (qty_on_order - qty_on_hand) as Sales 
from 
(select rnk,product_name, (qty_on_order - qty_on_hand) as Sales,
rank() over (PARTITION BY  product_name ORDER BY Sales DESC) as rnk
from products, product_inventory)
where rnk <= 3;